# Set bigint length to infinity

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set the length to infinity of one of the field of my database table whose data type is integer (BIGINT). Kindly let me know how can I set the length of the field to infinity/unlimited?

```
Column  Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
1        id    bigint(255)      No      None    AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: What do you mean by *...set the length of the field to infinity/unlimited*???

Comment: @peterm I meant set it to the maximum number it is allowed to store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For maximum values take a look at [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html)

BIGINT SIGNED - 9223372036854775807
BIGINT UNSIGNED - 18446744073709551615

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Table1(`col1` BIGINT, `col2` BIGINT UNSIGNED);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> DESC table1;
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| col1  | bigint(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| col2  | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(9223372036854775807, 18446744073709551615);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM Table1;
+---------------------+----------------------+
| col1                | col2                 |
+---------------------+----------------------+
| 9223372036854775807 | 18446744073709551615 |
+---------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I gave `18446744073709551615` in length but it was not accepted

Comment: @user2304394 Please show how did you do that. Was your column of type `BIGINT UNSIGNED`?

Comment: @user2304394: These are maximum *values*, not lengths.

Comment: @peterm thanks your update solves what I have been looking for

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. All `*INT` fields have a fixed length that directly relates to the size of integers in various programming languages (and in particular, C). Even `DECIMAL` has a maximum size. If you need larger than it provides then use one of the `*TEXT` fields to hold the value as a string, but be aware that even those have limitations.

Comment: Well, if OP wants to store exact value of `PI` decimal digits, then we have bad news for him since even `4Gb` in `TEXT` data type will not enough for that. (_I think if `BIGINT` isn't enough, then something went wrong_)

Comment: what should be the maximum length for data type bigint?

Comment: @user2304394: Count up the digits in [peterm's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20138520/20862). That's the maximum length for `BIGINT`. In programming terms, 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not allowed in DBMS, but some DBMS like MSDE 2000 can accept the infinite float value. but it is a fatal error if you save this value.

i mean are sure your application needs such kind of data without having no errors. ?

```
BIGINT range is:
-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 normal. 0 to 18446744073709551615 UNSIGNED*. 
The maximum number of digits may be specified in parenthesis
```

if you query this infinite OR NaN data , your DB may corrupt or throw a fatal error.
That is why it is recommned to better use Exceptional handling before querying if you have no idea about the stored data.